# Pytorch Import Error: <pathname>: object file has no loadable segments

Tags: pytorch, ubuntu-16.04, importerror

I've been trying to install the Pytorch module for my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS through conda. I used `conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch` to install it (non CUDA version). However when I type `import torch` on the Python shell, this is what I see -

```
ImportError: /home/student/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/_C.so: object file has no loadable segments
```

I have verified that Pytorch was installed using `conda list`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04 for `conda env with python 3.8`. The problem I think is for the incomplete torch installation. So I did `pip install from wheel` instead of `conda install`. You may follow as below (assuming you have cuda11 installed):

1. create conda env

```
conda create --name=myenv python=3.8
conda activate myenv
```

2. Install torch from wheel

```
pip install torch==1.7.0+cu110 torchvision==0.8.1+cu110 torchaudio===0.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Please note I had to install `torchvision==0.8.1+cu110` as reported [here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/2912)